# Not able to download artifact from Nexus using curl

Tags: rest, maven, curl, nexus

I am trying to download an artifact from Nexus Pro 3.37.3-02 using curl but it is not working. I have found below commands which I think working for many other but in my case I am getting repository, maven.groupId, maven.artifactId, maven.baseVersion, maven.extension is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch files.

curl -u usename:password -L -X GET https://MY_NEXUS/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=MY-REPO&maven.groupId=MY_GROUP&maven.artifactId=MY_ARTIFACT_NAME&maven.baseVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=zip

I have followed this documentation to make this command.
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/search-api

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Do you get an error ? What does curl tell you ? Status code? Is the given repository a snapshot repo ?

Comment: Yes its an snapshot repository and this is the error i am getting  {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED", "message": "access to the requested resource is not authorized", " detail":null}]}
My credentials are correct and I am able to download the artifact from the nexus interface with same credentials.

Comment: I have also tried to use token username and password instead of plain username and password but getting below.  {
 "schemaVersion": 2,
 "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json", 
 " manifest": [
  {
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
   "size": 1155,
   "digest": "jkgj"
   "platform": {
                 "architecture": " amd64"
                  "os": "linux"
                       }
   }
                ]
}
Same warning comes for maven.groupId, maven.artifactId, maven.baseVersion and maven.extension.

Comment: First you should try to solve the issue: `UNAUTHORIZED`...

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem is fixed by using token and token password instead of plain username/password and adding double quotes around the url as below.

Comment: curl -u token:tokenPassword -L -X GET "https://MY_NEXUS/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=MY-REPO&group=MY_GROUP&name=MY_ARTIFACT_NAME&maven.baseVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=zip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if anyone else facing the same problem then this is the solution which worked for me.

```
curl -u token:tokenPassword -L -X GET "https://MY_NEXUS/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=MY-REPO&group=MY_GROUP&name=MY_ARTIFACT_NAME&version=MY_Version&maven.extension=zip" --output My_Artifact.zip
```